How to set up an Office 365 SMTP on Bitwarden?
I am running a self-hosted Bitwarden server. I installed it as per documentation. However I am running into an error when attempting to send the verification email, the error is as follows:
An error has occurred. An unhandled server error has occurred.

How do I configure a SMTP connection on Bitwarden for Microsoft Office 365?
My current ./bwdata/env/global.override.env setting are:
globalSettings__mail__replyToEmail=admin@example.org
globalSettings__mail__smtp__host=smtp.office365.com
globalSettings__mail__smtp__port=587
globalSettings__mail__smtp__ssl=true
globalSettings__mail__smtp__username=admin@example.org
globalSettings__mail__smtp__password=******
globalSettings__disableUserRegistration=false
adminSettings__admins=admin@example.org

I already checked and the SMTP for this account is enabled.
